# Evenly Split AB Testing Groups

Tags: python, pandas, experimental-design

I'm trying to evenly split a cohort of customers to minimize the difference between multiple categories for an AB test. I'd like to ensure the average for treatment and control groups for age, prior_sales, and the income's columns are the smallest they can be.

Additionally, I need to ensure each sales_person would maintain the same number of customers. For example, if they started with 20 customer_ids and we split 50% into treatment each sales_person would have 10 customer_ids.

I've been trying to figure out how to do programmatically without manually checking changes in excel so any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Sample data

| customer_id | age | prior_sales | income | sales_person | Group |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 34 | 500 | 50000 | Tom | Treatment |
| 2 | 42 | 600 | 90000 | Sarah | Control |
| 3 | 22 | 300 | 70000 | Tom | Control |
| 4 | 34 | 400 | 95000 | Tom | Treatment |
| 5 | 25 | 300 | 45000 | Sarah | Treatment |
| 6 | 64 | 150 | 125000 | Jerry | Treatment |
| 7 | 27 | 200 | 85000 | Sarah | Control |
| 8 | 49 | 750 | 105000 | Jerry | Control |

Comment: This is an optimisation problem. You could probably knock up a working solution in a few hours using simulated annealing https://github.com/perrygeo/simanneal

Comment: In order to get an even split, its easiest to combine the id with a "salt" (random value that is stable for a given a/b test), hash the result of that, and compare it to find out if its in the first 50% or second 50%.

In order to find a salt that distributes these properties most evenly - just brute force it!  Try a few hundred salts, and see how the user properties are distributed

Disclaimer: I work at Statsig, an a/b testing platform.  We do this bucketing in our sdks (you could use this in a node script) https://github.com/statsig-io/node-js-server-sdk/blob/main/src/Evaluator.ts#L455